# Converting from Modified to Standard Denavit Hartenberg

Tags: kinematics, matlab, forward-kinematics, manipulator, dh-parameters

This is probably a noob question.

But as of right **now I am having difficulty converting from the Modified DH to a Standard DH parameters** for the Franka Emika Panda. I need standard because it allows me to avoid recoding a lot of my other functions.

The modified DH parameters are provided in the following link:
https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/control_parameters.html#constants

```
    Joint   a(m)     d(m)     α(rad)   θ(rad)
------------------------------------------
Joint 1     0        0.333    0         θ1*
Joint 2     0        0        −π/2      θ2*
Joint 3     0        0.316    π/2       θ3*
Joint 4     0.0825   0        π/2        θ4*
Joint 5     -0.0825  0.384    −π/2       θ5*
Joint 6     0        0        π/2        θ6*
Joint 7     0.088    0        π/2        θ7*
Flange      0        0.107    0         0
```

[image: Franka Emika Panda in MDH]

I suspect my brain has frozen in favor of idiocy as I tried finding the parameters by doing it by hand, but right now I am consistently getting something that doesn't look right is there someone who can help me out?

**And to the bigger question: is there like an efficient way of doing this "matlab, python, etc"? Like a nice conversion method/strategy/algorithm etc?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Is it really just shifting the *a(m)* and *alpha(m)* parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no automated way to convert between different DH parameter conventions.  See my similar question here: [How to convert between classic and modified DH parameters?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/how-to-convert-between-classic-and-modified-dh-parameters)

Also, you might be interested in this paper: "[Lipkin 2005: A Note on Denavit-Hartenberg Notation in Robotics](https://web.archive.org/web/20121119091715/http://profesores.usfq.edu.ec:80/laurents/IME440/DETC2005-85460_DenavitHartenberg.pdf)".  It explains the **3** main DH parameter conventions and how they differ.  It is also good background reading on DH parameters.